# Elastic Search Hightlight with copy_to

Tags: elasticsearch

I have created the index with the following mapping:

```
PUT test
 {
    "mappings": {
        "documents": {
            "properties": {
                "name": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                },

                "fields": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                        "uid": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        },
                        "value": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "copy_to": "fulltext"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "fulltext": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "locale": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                },
                "title": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "raw": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "url": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "raw": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

I have added following two documents into it:

```
POST test/documents/10
{
  "title":"java",
  "url":"/java",
  "name":"two",
  "locale":"en-us",
  "fields":[{
    "uid":"group.name",
    "value":"my demo"
  },{
    "uid":"group.last",
    "value":"test"
  }]
}

POST test/documents/11
{
  "title":"php",
  "url":"/php",
  "name":"one",
  "locale":"en-us",
  "fields":[{
    "uid":"group.name",
    "value":"demo"
  },{
    "uid":"group.last",
    "value":"test"
  }]
}
```

and using the following query to search result:

```
GET test/_search
{
    "size": 10,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                "simple_query_string": {
                    "query": "my",
                    "fields": ["title^6", "url^4", "fulltext"]
                }
            }, {
                "terms": {
                    "locale": ["en-us"]
                }
            }, {
                "terms": {
                    "name": ["one","two"]
                }
            }]
        }
    },
    "highlight": {
        "pre_tags": ["<b>"],
        "post_tags": ["</b>"],
        "fields": {
            "*": {}
        }
    }
}
```

and get the following result:

```
{
  "took": 7,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 2.287682,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "documents",
        "_id": "10",
        "_score": 2.287682,
        "_source": {
          "title": "java",
          "url": "/java",
          "name": "two",
          "locale": "en-us",
          "fields": [
            {
              "uid": "group.name",
              "value": "my demo"
            },
            {
              "uid": "group.last",
              "value": "test"
            }
          ]
        },
        "highlight": {
          "name": [
            "<b>two</b>"
          ],
          "locale": [
            "<b>en-us</b>"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

above response highlighting name and locale section. I don't want to highlight name and locale I want to highlight only that text that I am searching(here word my).

How I can remove name and locale from highlight and highlights the actual word (here is "my")

Please help me into this?

Comment: but you search by locale and name, that's why they are highlighted as well

Comment: Is any way to remove it from search and highlight exact word? here also highlight not showing search text(here I am searching word "my")

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your query is following - simple query string have a special syntax. In your case, when it's `my` it means [implicitly](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-simple-query-string-query.html#_simple_query_string_syntax) it's a `should` clause, meaning it's not required for a match. This is why you get not highlighting for this `my` value. You either need to change the query or put a `+` before `my` to make this match - required.

Regarding the other parts of the query, that you do not want to see in highlighting, you could specify which fields you want to highlight, so instead of `*` in

```
"fields": {
            "*": {}
}
```

you could have fields, that you want - in your case, I assume it's `title, url, fulltext`. Take a look into [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html) to check it out

Answer (score 0):

Just say highlight to not highlight everything with "*" inside fields.

Also I suggest add your term-searches inside filter if you only need 1/0 as score for them in search.

```
GET test/_search
{
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "simple_query_string": {
            "query": "my",
            "fields": [
              "title^6",
              "url^4",
              "fulltext"
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "locale": [
              "en-us"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "name": [
              "one",
              "two"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "pre_tags": [
      "<b>"
    ],
    "post_tags": [
      "</b>"
    ],
    "fields": {
      "name": {},
      "title":{},
      "url": {},
      "fulltext": {}
    }
  }
}
```